# Show that if $f'$ is strictly increasing, then $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is increasing over $(0,\infty)$

Tags: calculus

> Suppose $f$ is a differentiable function over $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(0) = 0$. Show that if $f'$ is strictly increasing, then $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is increasing over $(0,\infty)$.

**Attempt:**

Since $f'$ is increasing we know that $f'' > 0$ for all $x$. Now let $g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x}$ and thus $f(x) = xg(x)$. Then we wish to show that $g'(x) > 0$ on $(0,\infty)$ and so since $f'(x) = xg'(x)+g(x)$ and $f''(x) = xg''(x)+2g'(x) > 0$, we have $g''(x) > \frac{-2g'(x)}{x}$. I am not sure how to use this though to prove the statement.

Comment: you don't know f'' exists.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By MVT, for some $c \in (0,x)$ such that $$\frac{f(x)}{x}=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(c)$$

Since $x>c$, this gives us that $$f'(x)>f'(c)=\frac{f(x)}{x}$$

Thus, $f'(x)x-f(x)>0$ if $x>0$.

But the derivative of $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is $$\frac{f'(x)x-f(x)}{x^2}>0$$Our proof is done.

Comment: Why is $x > c$?

Comment: @user19405892 Because $c \in (0,x)$ means that $0<c<x$.

Answer (score 0):

This proof is valid only if $f$ is twice differentiable. By Taylor, for some $c\in(0,x)$ and $x>0$,($c=c(x)$) :
$$f(x)=f'(0)x+f''(c)x^2$$
then
$$\frac{f(x)}{x}=f'(0)+f''(c)x$$
differentiating on both sides
$$g'(x)=f''(c)>0$$
for every $c(x)$.